# Problems with ssh

Tags: ssh, openssh

I have two VMs running Ubuntu server 16.04 on the same host machine, let us call them A and B.  They have different MAC addresses, which are both allowed on the network and can both access the Internet. I can use putty to ssh into both VMs.  I can use B to ssh into A. However, I cannot use A to ssh into B, since I consistently get a "permission denied (password)" error. It doesn't even get to the point where it asks me to enter my username.  The command I am running is:

```
ssh -p 6600 MY_IP
```

where I've added port forwarding from port 6600 to port 22, on which B listens to incoming ssh requests.  Since putty *can* ssh into B, I assume this isn't an ssh setting issue.

Any ideas?  I have installed openssh and I believe that's what I'm using.

Comment: Do you use the exact same username on both machines? If not, you'll need to specify which user you're logging in as (you must log in as a user that exists *on the remote machine*). For example, if the remote machine has a user named "bob", you can `ssh -p 6600 bob@MY_IP`

Comment: They are identical, yes, and using userB@MY_IP in the command results in the same error.  Also, creating a new user on B doesn't help.  And remember, I can still log in with putty, which is what is so weird

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the problem was with A's ssh_config file.  It had PasswordAuthentication set to "no", with all other authentication methods commented out (which I believe means they are set to default?)

Answer (score 0):

You have used command incorrectly.

> ssh username@ip

The error also may occur if you have enabled password less authentication and disabled password authentication in ssh_config file.

As mentioned in the comments it may be because of error in config file.

Comment: As per the answer above, the problem was with ssh_config having password authentication disabled.